# Given distances and values array, return sorted filtered values in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I am not sure what the title of this question should be.  But lets say we have 2 arrays, values and distances.

```
values = np.array([[-1,-1,-1],
                   [1, 2, 0],
                   [-1,-1,-1]])

distances = np.array([[1,2,3],
                      [6,5,4],
                      [7,8,9]])
```

I would like to get the values that are non negative, and have them in order by its corresponding distance, based on the distances array.

So with the example above, the positive values are `[1,2,0]` and its distances will be `[6,5,4]`.  Thus, if sorting by its corresponding distance, I would like to have `[0,2,1]` as the answer.

My code is below.  It works, but would like to have the solution of just using numpy.  Im sure that would be more efficient than this:

```
import numpy as np   
import heapq

def get_sorted_values(seek_val, values, distances):
    r, c = np.where(values >= seek_val)

    di = distances[r, c]
    vals = values[r, c]

    print("di", di)
    print("vals", vals)

    if len(di) >= 1:

        heap = []
        for d, v in zip(di,vals):
            heapq.heappush(heap, (d,v))

        lists = []
        while heap:
            d, v = heapq.heappop(heap)
            lists.append(v)

        return lists

    else:
        ## NOTHING FOUND
        return None
```

Input:

```
seek_val = 0
values = np.array([[-1,-1,-1],
                   [1,2,0],
                   [-1,-1,-1]])
distances = np.array([[1,2,3],
                      [6,5,4],
                      [7,8,9]])

print("Ans:",get_sorted_values(seek_val, values, distances))
```

Output:

```
di [6 5 4]
vals [1 2 0]
Ans: [0, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"one liner":

```
values[np.where(values >= 0)][np.argsort(distances[np.where(values >= 0)])]  

Out[981]: array([0, 2, 1])
```

repeating `np.where(values >= 0)` is inefficient, could make a variable if `values` is big

```
v_indx = np.where(values >= 0)
values[v_indx][np.argsort(distances[v_indx])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([[-1,-1,-1],
                   [ 1, 2, 0],
                   [-1,-1,-1]])
distances = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                      [6, 5, 4],
                      [7, 8, 9]])
print(values[values >= 0])
# [1 2 0]
print(distances[values >= 0])
# [6 5 4]
print('Ans:', values[values >= 0][np.argsort(distances[values >= 0])])
# Ans: [0 2 1]
```